# BufferStrategy, multiple exceptions and errors in Java

Tags: java, swing, exception

I'm trying to make a fairly basic 3D game in preparation for what's to come when I enter Ludum Dare 23, an annual game competition.

I'm using Java and I'm using Swing and AWT. (I'm using JFrame to create my window (obviously? idk))

The problem I'm having is occurring when I'm attempting to draw pixels on the screen. I get a number of exceptions regarding `BufferStrategy` and what's apparently a Thread issue.

The following is what the console box in Eclipse is throwing me.

```
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Component must have a valid peer
    at java.awt.Component$FlipBufferStrategy.createBuffers(Component.java:3982)
    at java.awt.Component$FlipBufferStrategy.<init>(Component.java:3956)
    at java.awt.Component$FlipSubRegionBufferStrategy.<init>(Component.java:4479)
    at java.awt.Component.createBufferStrategy(Component.java:3833)
    at java.awt.Canvas.createBufferStrategy(Canvas.java:194)
    at java.awt.Component.createBufferStrategy(Component.java:3756)
    at java.awt.Canvas.createBufferStrategy(Canvas.java:169)
    at com.ottdev.tale.TaleOfDwarvesComponent.render(TaleOfDwarvesComponent.java:66)
    at com.ottdev.tale.TaleOfDwarvesComponent.run(TaleOfDwarvesComponent.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Any ideas on how I could solve this issue? It's doing my head in and is preventing me from advancing.  All help is highly appreciated!

PS: I can put up my source code if need be, but for now, I'd rather know *how* to fix it so I can know what to do if I encounter this situation in the future, but with different code.

EDIT: My main class - 
TaleOfDwarvesComponent:

```
package com.ottdev.tale;    
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;

import javax.swing.*;

import com.ottdev.tale.gui.*;

public class TaleOfDwarvesComponent extends Canvas implements Runnable {
    public static final int WIDTH = 800;
    public static final int HEIGHT = 600;
    public static final int SCALE = 2;
    public static final String TITLE = "Tale Of Dwarves!";

    private boolean running = false;
    private BufferedImage img;
    public int[] pixels;
    private Thread thread;
    private Game game;
    private Screen screen;

    public TaleOfDwarvesComponent() {
        game = new Game();
        screen = new Screen(WIDTH, HEIGHT);

        img = new BufferedImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        pixels = ((DataBufferInt) img.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();



    }

    public void start() {
        if (running)
            return;
        running = true;
        new Thread(this).start();
    }

    public void stop() {
        if (!running)
            return;
        running = false;
        try{
            thread.join();
        }catch(InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void run() {
        while(running){
            render();
        }
    }

    public void tick(){
        game.tick();
    }

    public void render(){

        BufferStrategy bs = getBufferStrategy();
        if(bs == null){
            createBufferStrategy(3);
            return;
        }
        screen.render(game);
        for (int i = 0; i < WIDTH * HEIGHT; i++){
            pixels[i] = screen.pixels[i];
        }

        Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT * SCALE, null);
        g.dispose();
        bs.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TaleOfDwarvesComponent game = new TaleOfDwarvesComponent();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setTitle(TITLE);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        game.start();

    }
}
```

I have a `Bitmap` class and a `Screen` class, but for now, I'll put this up in hope that the answer to my troubles can be obtained from this.

Comment: Make sure you are drawing on a `JPanel` and not the frame directly.

Comment: *"Josh, UK."*  If I cared who you were, I'd check your ID.  If I cared where you were from, I'd check [your profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1322561/ottahhh).  Please leave such noise out of questions.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the javadocs http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Canvas.html#createBufferStrategy(int)

I believe it specifically addresses your problem, that is, that you are calling createBufferStrategy before the Canvas is displayed on the screen. So to solve your problem, you need to either add a ComponentListener to your Canvas and call createBufferStrategy on componentShown, or call this in your paint method

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply, I somewhat understand what your saying, but I'm somewhat confused as to how to fix it(if that makes sense :P), therefore, I'm going to resort to posting the source, I will update the post and hopefully you can further educate me on what I must do.

Comment: Just stop calling createBufferStrategy!

Comment: Your problem is where you call screen.render. Look at the stacktrace

Comment: lol, I'm definitely being retarded now, I don't understand whats wrong with it -.- I'm fairly newish to Java, so I'm still not clear on everything, sorry if I seem like I'm acting like a complete idiot ;D Could you explain what I actually have to change? I know in my post I said id rather not know exactly what, but I'm finding this harder to comprehend than I thought I would xD

Comment: I've tried a couple of things now, but none of them have worked... I'm honestly stumped.

Comment: Abandon what you've done and find a tutorial or some sample code. It is the best way to get started.

Comment: I don't particularly  want to do that, could you not just tell me what I have to move or what not to fix that?